# excel file is closing UserForm1

Tags: excel, vba

I have an xlsm file, when I open it a UserForm1 is opened and the excel file is made invisible. Now when I open another file, UserForm1 stays open, so far everything is fine, but when I close the other Excel file, UserForm1 is also automatically closed, which I don't actually want.

steps I take:

1. I open xlsm file, this opens UserForm1 and excel becomes invisible.
2. I open another xls file
3. I close this xls file
   after step 3 UserForm1 also closes, I don't want that.

if anyone wants to reproduce my code:

**This workbook:**

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

    showLoginForm
    
    
End Sub
```

**UserForm1:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub EditMode_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

**Module:**

```
Sub showLoginForm()
    If isSheetVisible Then
        ' Only Hide this workbook and keep the other workbooks visible
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        ' There is no other workbook visible, hide Excel
        Application.Visible = False
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    End If
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Function isSheetVisible() As Boolean
    ' Checks if any workbook except the current one is visible
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
            Dim win As Window
            For Each win In wb.Windows
                If win.Visible Then isSheetVisible = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the fix you want, but it might get you closer to the behavior you need. When you close the second workbook this will reopen the user form.  To actually close the first workbook click on the new added command button.

in **Module1** add this code

```
Dim bOkToClose As Boolean
Sub OkToClose()
    bOkToClose = True
End Sub
Function isOkToClose() As Boolean
    isOkToClose = bOkToClose
End Function
```

in the **UserForm1** add another command button to actually close the workbook, and this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Module1.OkToClose
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

in **ThisWorkBook** add this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Module1.isOkToClose Then Exit Sub
        'return the user form to visible, and retain workbook open
        Cancel = True
        UserForm1.Show
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, the only thing is, that now the second workbook doesnt close, if I click "X" at right corner it reopens the userform1 from the first workbook. But it should also close the workbook which is open - so second or third or what ever which workbook it is.

Comment: The new button on the form is how the "first" work book is actually closed, not the X.  You can modify the logic in that button to also close any opened workbook, or if you have specific names, just those.

Comment: I mean if I want to close another excel file, while i have open userform1 (from main exel file) i have to close thought the "x" at right corner. And if i do it, the userform1 just reopens, but how do i close the another excel file from "x" while userform1 stays open or reopens. I hope i could explain my problem :/

Comment: without knowing the purpose of the userform or the main workbook, I don't follow what the objective is.  When the main workbook is hidden, and any other work book is closed, excel will also close the hidden work book.  The logic provided gives you control over that, and prevents the main wb from closing.  What you do with that...?

Comment: i just want to use this UserForm as an "independent" UI, which then contains information about what is in the excel list. e.g. i have windows links etc. in this UserForm. I also know how to do it e.g. in the python language with pyqt5 but I dont have the possibility to install python on the pc and therefore I do it with excel vba userform. Actually quite simple, as I said I just want to use this UserForm as UI. When I open or close another Excel document, this UserForm should not be affected by it.

Comment: but at the moment if i open a completely independent excel document nothing happens so the UserForm is not affected but as soon as i close this other excel file, the UserForm closes too, i don't want that.  I don't understand, let's say we don't have a vba or something and we have two excel files, if I close one, the other one doesn't close, why doesn't it work here and as soon as I close another excel file, the UserForm also closes....

Comment: excel will not support what you are trying to do.  Suggest you otherwise manage the main wb, by possibly setting the key worksheets to visibility = vbveryhidden, and maybe minimize that wb or locate it out of the way.  But once you set the visibility to false it will react to closing any other wb.

Comment: Oh no thats sad... How does the code look like with vbveryhidden? And locate it out of the way?

Comment: worksheet(name or index number).visibility = xlSheetVeryHidden

Comment: Im trying to do what you say, so ill try to work with/on Sheet cuz Excel doesnt support it use like UI. But i stuck with filtering the buttons. Maybe you can help me. The question link is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78033768/search-and-reposition-buttons-excel-with-textbox